# Native usage of けど

Tags: particles

I understand that けれども/けれど/けど means "although, however, but", but I'm looking for the daily usage of it.

It looks like that native Japanese use this particle not only when they are trying to contradict two things. Would any native level Japanese speaker show some example of けれども/けれど/けど that will make me sound more Japanese please?

An example would be (I heard this when I was buying a train ticket, someone said to the train station staff):

> ◯◯に行きたいんですけど…

Doesn't make sense to me. I suspect this is due to Japanese culture.

Comment: <noun>ですけど is sometimes used as a topic marker. の changes the clause preceding it into a noun. ◯◯に行きたい is the thing you want to bring up. 教えていただけませんか is what you really want to say but omitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply, けど is also often used as a softener. That way, they don't sound as abrupt or rude.

> ◯◯に行きたいんですけど…

The speaker added けど to make sure (s)he didn't sound like, "I want to go to ◯◯!" when trying to get a ticket.

Comment: So, does this mean that I can add けど whenever I want to make my request sound more polite?

Comment: Not in **all** cases, but in many, yes. けど is better for less formal situation, or when you're speaking to someone who is 'at that moment' viewed as lower status than you, such as when you're a customer speaking to a worker. In more formal situations, use the longer forms or ですが。

Answer (score 2):

I happened to see your question. Let me add my thought to two answers.

When someone stopped own claim at

...けど,

sometimes this means question or emphasis or omission, or some combination of them.

In the situation of the train station, I guess the usage is question. When Japanese expect/think that a person understand one's opinion, then omit one's claim. In that station, I guess "the someone" "omit a question".

In the situation of you read a diary, I can't guess "precise" meaning of ...けど because I don't see the context. But I expect that meaning is one of three or combination of them.

In conversation someone stopped ...けど and I don't understand their claim, I often throw a question back at them.

けど/ですけど/ですが

have many means, I think the context is important.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that けれども/けれど/けど means "although, however, but", but I'm looking for the daily usage of it.

I mostly hear けど in daily life conversations. The two other sound more "formal/feminine" to me.

> > ◯◯に行きたいんですけど…

This is one the multuous unsaid things in japanese.

◯◯に行きたいんですが、どうしたらいいですか。

◯◯に行きたいんですが、地図を書いていただけませんか。

which you shouldn't be translate word by word but instead should be understood as:

”I'd like to go to oo, could you do that or this to hep me?”

If you don't say the second part, it becomes softer, as if you were reluctant of asking something (but by doing so you let your interlocutor guessing what you want)

◯◯に行きたいんですが...

in a less polite way of speaking, が becomes けど

Answer (score 0):

東京に行きたいんですけど　(行き方がわかりません)

The words "I don't know how to get there." are hidden, I think.